# Input requerido si está visible y no si está oculto

Tags: jquery, input

Tengo un campo de un formulario (pickbox) que se muestra o no dependiendo del valor de otro campo (pick) pero necesito que al mostrarse sea obligatorio (required) y que no lo sea al ocultarse?

```
$('#pickbox').css('display','none');
$('#pick').on("change",function(){
  if ($('#pick').val() == '2') {
             $('#pickbox').css('display','block');

  }else if ($('#pick').val() == '1') {
             $('#pickbox').css('display','none');
  }
});
```

Comment: It would be ideal if you translated the question into Spanish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el siguiente código, donde verás que se usan los métodos [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) y [removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) de jquery para agregar o quitar el atributo **required**:

```js
$('#pickbox').css('display', 'none');
$('#pick').on("change", function() {
  if ($('#pick').val() == '2') {
    $('#pickbox').css('display', 'block');
    $('#pickbox').attr('required', 'required');

  } else if ($('#pick').val() == '1') {
    $('#pickbox').css('display', 'none');
    $('#pickbox').removeAttr('required');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<input id="pickbox">
<input id="pick" type="number" >
```

Comment: Solucionado. tenia el attr. aplicado al form-control, no al input.